# Do you have any suggestions to make this equations system more legible

Tags: equations, align

I have the following equation system. I am aware that it does not look legible and as it is for my thesis (not in mathematics), I was wondering if anyone could help with making it more legible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\maxmin}
\setlength{\maxmin}{\widthof{$\max$}-\widthof{$\min$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \left |{\dfrac{ Im \left[S_{na}(n_{i}f_{0})\right]}{Im \left[S_{na}    ((n_{i}+2)f_{0})\right]}}\right|  \geq 1
  \begin{cases}
    \begin{cases}
      1 \leq \left |{\dfrac{ Im \left[S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0})\right]}{Im     \left[S_{a}((n_{i}+2)f_{0})\right]}}\right| \leq 1+\frac{2}{n}  \\
       \sqrt{\left|   \dfrac{(n+2)Im \left[S_{a}((n_{i}+2)f_{0})\right] - n     Im \left[S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0})\right]}{n(n+2)^2 Im \left[S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0})\right] -     (n+2)n^2 Im \left[S_{a}((n_{i}+2)f_{0})\right]} \right|} \leq  \phi
    \end{cases}

   &\text{Or} \\

    \begin{cases}
      \left |{\dfrac{ Im \left[S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0})\right]}{Im \left[S_{a}    ((n_{i}+2)f_{0})\right]}}\right| \geq 1+\frac{2}{n} \\

      \forall \phi \in \mathbb{R_{+}}
    \end{cases}

  \end{cases}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
  \left |{\dfrac{ Im \left[S_{na}(n_{i}f_{0})\right]}{Im \left[S_{na}    ((n_{i}+2)f_{0})\right]}}\right|  \leq 1
  \begin{cases}
    \begin{cases}
      1 \leq \left |{\dfrac{ Im \left[S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0})\right]}{Im     \left[S_{a}((n_{i}+2)f_{0})\right]}}\right| \leq 1+\frac{2}{n}  \\
       \sqrt{\left|   \dfrac{(n+2)Im \left[S_{a}((n_{i}+2)f_{0})\right] - n     Im \left[S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0})\right]}{n(n+2)^2 Im \left[S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0})\right] -     (n+2)n^2 Im \left[S_{a}((n_{i}+2)f_{0})\right]} \right|} \geq  \phi
    \end{cases}

  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

$\forall\ \  n_{i} =\{2k+1, k\in \mathbb {N} \}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Your second line is contradictory: if I understand well, it is the case, and the expression on the left of the big brace is supposed to be ≤ 1, but in the first line on the right, it is between 1 and 1+2/n!

Comment: It won't change much in this case, but `Im` written as it is now in your code means “the product of a variable I and a variable m”. I doubt that's what you mean. Consider using `\mathit` or `\mathrm` or `\operatorname` or `\Im` or something else, depending on what it's supposed to express. Just writing letters one after another in math mode makes the kerning look rather bad (try compiling `ff \mathit{ff}` and you'll see the difference, I think).

Comment: Thank you for the hint @Bernard ! I had a mistake in the indices

Comment: That may be important to decide the final layout, as it is linked to the semantics of the formula.

Comment: @Bernard, I am open to any suggestions. $Im$ stands for Imaginary part. $S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0}) stands for a frequency spectrum $S_{a}$ at the higher harmonic $n_{i}f_{0}$.

Comment: Could you make the correction so you formulae are consistent?

Comment: please make your code compilable :) it is erronous

Comment: @Zarko, it is compilable to me. Sorry!

Comment: @Bernard I edited it.

Comment: no, it is not. at least are missing `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` ...

Comment: the math aspect is off-topic here, but the formatting of the equations is entirely dependent on it.  sorry, but I don't understand what should your equation tell to reader ... so it is difficult to help you.

Comment: To the left of the curly braces, there are terms involving `S_{na}`, whereas to the right, there are terms involving `S_{a}`. Is that a typo, or is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses a single `align` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert} % modulus
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}                 % imaginary part

\newcommand{\sa}{ S_{\textit{a} }}
\newcommand{\sna}{S_{\textit{na}}}
\newcommand{\terma}{ \im\bigl[\sa (n_{i}f_{0})\bigr]}
\newcommand{\terman}{\im\bigl[\sna(n_{i}f_{0})\bigr]}
\newcommand{\termb}{ \im\bigl[\sa \bigl((n_{i}+2)f_{0}\bigr)\bigr]}
\newcommand{\termbn}{\im\bigl[\sna\bigl((n_{i}+2)f_{0}\bigr)\bigr]}
\newcommand{\termc}{ \abs[\bigg]{\frac{\terma }{\termb }}}
\newcommand{\termcn}{\abs[\bigg]{\dfrac{\terman}{\termbn}}}
\newcommand{\termd}{ \abs[\bigg]{\frac{(n+2)\termb 
       - n\terma}{n(n+2)^2\terma - n^2(n+2)\termb}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\shortintertext{$\termcn\geq1\colon$}
&\begin{dcases}
    1\leq\termc\leq 1+2/n \\[1.25ex]
    \termd \leq \phi'
 \end{dcases}  \label{eq:first}\\
\shortintertext{or}
&\begin{dcases}
    \termc\geq 1+2/n \\[1ex]
    \forall \phi'\in\mathbb{R_+}
 \end{dcases}  \label{eq:first_prime}\tag{$\ref{eq:first}'$}\\[2ex]
\shortintertext{$\termcn\leq1\colon$}
&\begin{dcases}
    1\leq\termc\leq 1+2/n \\[1.25ex]
    \termd \geq \phi'
 \end{dcases} \label{eq:second}
\end{align}
for all $n_i=2k+1$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Some cross-references: equations \eqref{eq:first}, \eqref{eq:first_prime}, and \eqref{eq:second}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because there are many redundancies in the formulas I would introduce some variables `s, t, x, y`.

For the funcion `Im` I declared an operator with `\DeclareMathOperator`. If you mean the Imaginary part of the number you should use `\Im`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Imx}{Im}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    s &\coloneqq \Imx \left[S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0})\right]
    \\
    t &\coloneqq \Imx \left[S_{a}((n_{i}+2)f_{0})\right]
    \\
    x &\coloneqq \left|\dfrac{s}{t}\right|
    \\
    y &\coloneqq \sqrt{\left|\dfrac{
        (n+2) \cdot t - n \cdot s
    }{
        n(n+2)^2 \cdot s - (n+2)n^2 \cdot t
    } \right|}
    \\
    x &\geq 1
    \begin{cases}
        \begin{cases}
            1 \leq x \leq 1+\frac{2}{n}  \\
            y \leq  \phi
        \end{cases}
        &\text{Or} \\
        \begin{cases}
            x \geq 1+\frac{2}{n} \\
            \forall \phi \in \mathbb{R}_{+}
        \end{cases}
    \end{cases}
    \\
    x &\leq 1
    \begin{cases}
        \begin{cases}
            1 \leq x \leq 1+\frac{2}{n}  \\
            y \geq  \phi
        \end{cases}
    \end{cases}
    \\
    &\forall\ \  n_{i} =\{2k+1, k\in \mathbb {N}\}\notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: Since the question was edited you now need another variable for the left part of the inequations, because now there is used `S_{na}`.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}
Let be
    \begin{align}
S_A     & = \dfrac{\Im \left[S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0})\right]}
                  {\Im \left[S_{a}((n_{i}+2)f_{0})\right]}  \\
S_A'    & = \dfrac{(n+2)\Im \left[S_{a}((n_{i}+2)f_{0})\right] -
                            n\Im\left[S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0})\right]}
                  {n(n+2)^2 \Im \left[S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0})\right] -
                            n^2(n+2) \Im \left[S_{a}((n_{i}+2)f_{0})\right]}
\intertext{than:}
    \left|\dfrac{\Im \left[S_{na}(n_{i}f_{0})\right]}
                {\Im \left[S_{na}((n_{i}+2)f_{0})\right]}\right|
        &   \geq 1 \Rightarrow
\begin{dcases}
    1 \leq \left| S_A  \right| \leq 1 + \dfrac{2}{n}    &   \\
     \sqrt{\left| S_A' \right|} \leq  \phi              &   \\
     \text{or}                                          &   \\
    \left | S_A \right| \geq 1+ \dfrac{2}{n}            &   \\
    \forall \phi \in \mathbb{R_{+}}                     &
\end{dcases}
\intertext{and}
    \left|\dfrac{\Im \left[S_{na} (n_{i}f_{0})\right]}
                {\Im \left[S_{na} ((n_{i}+2)f_{0})\right]}\right|
        &   \leq 1 \Rightarrow
\begin{dcases}
      1 \leq \left| S_A  \right| \leq 1+\dfrac{2}{n}     &   \\
       \sqrt{\left| S_A' \right|} \geq  \phi
\end{dcases}
\end{align}
for all $\{2k+1, k\in \mathbb {N} \}$

\end{document}
```

**edit:**

as i mentioned in comment below question, for setting these equations you need to understand, what they like tell to readers. i suspect that equation (3) in above *mwe* is wrong and should be as it is written in *mwe* below.

in *mwe* below are also introduced new command `\abs{...}` for use instead of `\left| ... \right|` and set difference in height in successive parents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\delimitershortfall-1sp
\newcommand\abs[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}

\begin{document}
Let be
    \begin{align}
S_A     & = \dfrac{\Im \left[S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0})\right]}
                  {\Im \left[S_{a}\left((n_{i}+2)f_{0}\right)\right]}  \\
S_A'    & = \dfrac{(n+2)\Im \left[S_{a}\left((n_{i}+2)f_{0}\right)\right] -
                            n\Im\left[S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0})\right]}
                  {n(n+2)^2 \Im \left[S_{a}\left(n_{i}f_{0}\right)\right] -
                            n^2(n+2) \Im \left[S_{a}\left((n_{i}+2)f_{0}\right)\right]}
\intertext{than:}
    \abs{\dfrac{\Im \left[S_{na}(n_{i}f_{0})\right]}
                {\Im \left[S_{na}\left((n_{i}+2)f_{0}\right)\right]}
        }
        & \geq 1 \Rightarrow
\begin{dcases}
    1 \leq \abs{ S_A }   \leq 1 + \dfrac{2}{n}          &   \\
    \sqrt{\abs{ S_A' }} \leq  \phi                      &   \\[1ex]
     \text{or}                                          &   \\
    \abs{ S_A } \geq 1+ \dfrac{2}{n},                   &  \forall \phi \in \mathbb{R_{+}}
\end{dcases}
\intertext{and}
    \abs{\dfrac{\Im \left[S_{na} \left(n_{i}f_{0}\right)\right]}
               {\Im \left[S_{na} \left((n_{i}+2)f_{0}\right)\right]}
        }
        &   \leq 1 \Rightarrow
\begin{dcases}
      1 \leq \abs{ S_A  } \leq 1+\dfrac{2}{n}           &   \\
       \sqrt{\abs{ S_A' }} \geq  \phi
\end{dcases}
\end{align}
for all $\{2k+1, k\in \mathbb {N} \}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You could simplify the expression even further by replacing the longish terms ahead of the inequality symbols in equations 3 and 4 with `\abs{S_A}`.

Comment: @Mico, those expression are not equal to `S_A` (they contain `S_{na}` and `SA` contain `S_{a}`). i'm not sure if this is intentionally or only typo error. to be honest, i not understand equation, i suspect that equation (3) should be as I wrote in edit of answer.

Comment: You're right -- I had overlooked the difference between `S_{a}` and `S_{na}`. For what it's worth, I don't understand the equation either...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `flalign`. I also defined a `\abs` command which has a starred version that adds a pair of `\left ... \right` to the pair of `\vert ... \rvert`, and accepts an optional argument (`\big`, `\Big`, &c.) to fine-tune the size of the delimiters. This requires loading `mathtools` (no need to load `amsmath` in this case).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsfonts}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\maxmin}
\setlength{\maxmin}{\widthof{$\max$}-\widthof{$\min$}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
  & \mathrlap{\abs*{\frac{ \im \bigl[S_{na}(n_{i}f_{0})\bigr]}{\im \bigl[S_{na}\bigl ((n_{i}+2)f_{0}\bigr)\bigr]}} \geq 1 :} \notag\\
  & & & \begin{dcases}
    1 \leq \abs*{\frac{ \im \bigl[S_{na}(n_{i}f_{0})\bigr]}{\im \bigl[S_{na}\bigl ((n_{i}+2)f_{0}\bigr)\bigr]}} \leq 1+\frac{2}{n} \\
    \sqrt{\abs*{ \frac{(n+2)\im \bigl[S_{a}\bigl((n_{i}+2)f_{0}\bigr)\bigr] - n \im \bigl[S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0})\bigr]}{n(n+2)^2 \im \bigl[S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0})\bigr] - (n+2)n^2 \im \bigl[S_{a}\bigl((n_{i}+2)f_{0}\bigr)\bigr]}}} \leq \phi
  \end{dcases}\notag & & \\
  & & \text{or} & \\
  & & & \begin{dcases}
    \abs*{\frac{ \im \bigl[S_{na}(n_{i}f_{0})\bigr]}{\im \bigl[S_{na}\bigl ((n_{i}+2)f_{0}\bigr)\bigr]}}\geq 1+\frac{2}{n} & \\
    \forall \phi  \in \mathbb{R_{+}}
  \end{dcases} \notag\\[3ex]
  & \mathrlap{\abs*{\frac{ \im \bigl[S_{na}(n_{i}f_{0})\bigr]}{\im \bigl[S_{na}\bigl ((n_{i}+2)f_{0}\bigr)\bigr]}} \leq 1:} \notag\\
  & & & \begin{dcases}
    1 \leq \abs*{\frac{ \im \bigl[S_{na}(n_{i}f_{0})\bigr]}{\im \bigl[S_{na}\bigl ((n_{i}+2)f_{0}\bigr)\bigr]}} \leq 1+\frac{2}{n} \\
    \sqrt{\abs*{ \frac{(n+2)\im \bigl[S_{a}\bigl((n_{i}+2)f_{0}\bigr)\bigr] - n \im \bigl[S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0})\bigr]}{n(n+2)^2 \im \bigl[S_{a}(n_{i}f_{0})\bigr] - (n+2)n^2 \im \bigl[S_{a}\bigl((n_{i}+2)f_{0}\bigr)\bigr]}}} \geq \phi
  \end{dcases}\\[1ex]
  \rlap{for all \enspace $ n_{i} =\{2k+1, k \in \mathbb {N} \} $}\notag
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]